# emacs: Font lock mode chooses light colors

Tags: emacs

It strains my eyes when `emacs` chooses to use light colors on light background.

[image: Screen with light text on light background]

Can I tell `emacs` not to use yellow on a light background?

Comment: Do you use a theme? How is `sh-heredoc` face customized?

Comment: @choroba I have not actively set anything up. How can I tell if it is the case?

Comment: `M-x describe-face` and probably `M-x customize-themes` (I don't use themes myself).

Comment: Consider moving your question to emacs.stackexchange.com